# Solve the trigonometric series equation $1 + \sin x + \sin^2 x + \sin^3 x + \cdots = 4 + 2\sqrt 3$

Tags: trigonometry, geometric-progressions

> $$1 + \sin x + \sin^2 x + \sin^3 x + \cdots = 4 + 2\sqrt 3$$
>   Find $x$.

What I first did was I applied addition of geometric progression condition that I just copied off a book.

That got me something like
$$\frac{1 - \sin^{\infty} x}{1 - \sin x} = 4 - 2 \sqrt 3,$$
and I got stuck.

Please tell me any step I've taken wrongly, or something new to help me solve the problem. I've recently started studying for IIT-JEE, and am a beginner who just stumbled upon this question. Please help me out.

Comment: Provided that $|u| < 1$, $1 + u + u^2 + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - u}$.

Comment: @Travis $|u|\lt 1$ not $0$

Comment: $|U|< \color{red}{1}$

Comment: Thanks for the catch, Guys.

Comment: Thanks guys. Help me answer as well.

Comment: Your problem is that $(1-\sin x)^{\infty})/(1 - \sin x) $ should be replaced by formula $(1)/(1 - \sin x) $ for an infinite geometrical sum.

Comment: How can sin x raised to infinity be 0? How will that help me solve the problem?

Comment: @AksharGandhi: what else than $0$ could it be ???

Comment: If $a<1$, $a^n\to 0$ if $n\to \infty$

Comment: Alright, thanks all of you, I'm answered.

Comment: If you are preparing for JEE you can join us at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48921/discussions-in-pcm-and-anything-else

Comment: since $|\sin x| < 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sin x)^n = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x \in \mathbb R |\sin x|\le1$ and if $|u|<1$ then $1+u+u^2+u^3+...=\frac1{1-u}$

$$\frac1{1-\sin x}=4+2\sqrt3$$

$$\sin x=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$x=(-1)^k\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: I want to know how sin x raised to infinity is 0. Explain that to me.

Comment: @Roman, are you saying that whatever you've typed about 'u' is a property?

Comment: @AksharGandhi: Yes

Comment: http://www.mathwords.com/i/infinite_geometric_series.htm

Answer (score 1):

Continuing after reading the comments,

You are to solve:$${1\over 1-\sin(x)}=4+2\sqrt 3$$

Now $1-\sin(x)$ can be written as $(\sin(x/2)-\cos(x/2))^2$ So proceed from here.

Also check that the right side is $(1+\sqrt 3)^2$